# JQuery iterate over array of dictionaries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of `dicts` returned by the server in an ajax request as:

```
var obj =  [{'id': '111', 'name': 'test1'}, {'id': '1975', 'name': 'test2'}]
```

When I try to access each dictionary as:

```
$.each(obj,function(index,value){ 
    alert(index + " : " + value);
});
```

I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '193' in [{'id': '111', 'name': 'test1'}, {'id': '1975', 'name': 'test2'}]

How can you access each dictionary in the array?

Comment: Your objects have an `u` in them that makes the whole thing invalid. You need to remove that.

Comment: is that `u''` notation a Python artifact?

Comment: Yes I have removed the `u`

Comment: Remove them in your code not the question and it will work

Comment: Seems ok to me: http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/7j47wm3h/

Comment: @AlexK. I believe he wants the alert boxes to display 'id': '111' then 'name': 'test1' etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need one $.each() for the array, and another for handle the elements of the dictionary (which, BTW, most JS programmers call an "object")

```
$.each(obj,function(index,value){ 
    $.each(value, function(index2, value2) {

                alert(index2 + " : " + value2);
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is anything wrong in code you have written, its perfectly right.

http://jsfiddle.net/neilmalgaonkar/3y79vr4s/

```
var obj=  [{'id': '111', 'name': 'test1'}, {'id': '1975', 'name': 'test2'}];

$.each(obj,function(index,value){ 
   console.log(index,  value);
});
```

just remove **u** from array it should work

Answer (score 0):

the `jQuery $.each` function is just a wrapper for `javascripts` for-in loop. The object you are trying to iterate is invalid.

The loop is looking for `key` and `value` based on that key. but the value `u'111'` is invalid js object notation.

**Edit:** You say you removed the 'u' but the error messages still says you have it...

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj=  [{'id': '111', 'name': 'test1'}, {'id': '1975', 'name': 'test2'}]

$(obj).each(function(index,value){ 

    alert("index: " + index + ",  id: " + value.id + ",  name: " + value.name);

});
```

working : http://jsfiddle.net/wvqkfb1f/

Comment: Thanks I get this error in the console: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: `